# Pandas group by unique value above a threshold

Tags: python, pandas

Tough one.

Start with this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'number':[4.4,11, 2.4,5, 12,22],
    'id': [1,1, 2,2, 3,3]
})
```

```
| number | id | 
|--------|----|
| 4.4    | 1  |
| 11     | 1  |
| 2.4    | 2  |
| 5      | 2  |
| 12     | 3  | 
| 22     | 3  |
```

I want to group by the `id` column, and add a third column called `unique_above_10` and set the value to 1 if there is one and only one value in the groupby that is > 10.

So the new DataFrame should look like this:

```
| number | id | unique_above_10 |
|--------|----|-----------------|
| 4.4    | 1  | 0               |
| 11     | 1  | 1               |
| 2.4    | 2  | 0               |
| 5      | 2  | 0               |
| 12     | 3  | 0               |
| 22     | 3  | 0               |
```

Comment: Shouldn't `unique_above_10` be equal for all rows that share a given `id`? Why is it 0 for the first row? Unless you mean that only the value that is indeed above 10 should get a `1`.

Comment: Yes only the row that has the sole unique maximum above 10 should be set to 1, hard to phrase this question

Comment: The sample input/output speaks for itself anyway, that's why it's great you added it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare values by mask and count matched values by `sum` per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), compare by `1` and chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` by mask `m`:

```
m = df['number'].gt(10)
df['unique_above_10'] = (m.groupby(df['id']).transform('sum').eq(1) & m).astype(int)
print (df)
   number  id  unique_above_10
0     4.4   1                0
1    11.0   1                1
2     2.4   2                0
3     5.0   2                0
4    12.0   3                0
5    22.0   3                0
```

**Details**:

```
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: number, dtype: bool

print (m.groupby(df['id']).transform('sum'))
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
Name: number, dtype: float64

print (m.groupby(df['id']).transform('sum').eq(1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: number, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the details. Learnt about `transform` thanks to you.

Comment: 2 things I've never seen before with Pandas(masks and transform), would never have worked that out!